# NSight Compute - get total number of samples?

Tags: cuda, profiling, nsight-compute

When you use NSight-Compute's Source, PTX or SASS view, you see the number of samples taken on each line. However, you don't see (or it is difficult to find) the *total* number of samples taken overall, which you would like to normalize by.

Is it listed somewhat inconspicuous or is it just missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it listed somewhat inconspicuous or is it just missing?

There is currently no dedicated metric or place in the tool where the total number of samples is shown. We will look into adding this in the future.

As a workaround, you should be able to collapse the source view using the +/- button, which aggregates the metrics, including samples, per function/file and makes it easier to manually count, should your kernel have multiple functions/files.

Comment: That's really too bad. Annoying oversight :-(

Comment: Say, FelixS, is there a way to pass feature requests to you guys better than through developer.nvidia.com bug reports? Like a tool-specific issue tracker, or devs-and-users discussion forum?

Comment: >  devs-and-users discussion forum
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/development-tools/nsight-compute